# Обособление несогласованного определения

Tags: пунктуация, определения

Он ходил в вицмундире (нужна ли тут запятая для отделения несогласованного определения от определяемого слова?) рыжевато-мучного цвета.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, запятая не нужна.

Определения, выраженные косвенными падежами имён существительных, как правило, стоят после определяемых слов.

Они обычно не обособляются, объединяясь с определяемым словом в словосочетание-называние, например: **Найдите там даму в серой шляпке с белой птицей и скажите, что я здесь. (Ч.)** Они обособляются, если только дополняют и уточняют пред­ставление об известном уже предмете или лице, например:

**Величественно вышла мать, в сиреневом платье, в кружевах, с длинной нитью жемчуга на шее. (М. Г.)** Определяемое суще­ствительное **мать** обозначает уже известное лицо, определения же только дополняют наше представление о матери в данный момент; поэтому определения обособлены.